# How to parse and access columns based on headers in file? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I believe this is a 3 step process but please bear with me.
I'm currently reading Shell output which is being saved to a file and the output looks like this:

**Current Output:**

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 123.345.789:1234        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23044/test          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5915            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      99800/./serv    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1501            0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

I'm trying to access each columns information based on the **header** value. This is something I was able to do in Powershell but not sure how to achieve it in Python.

**Expected Output:**

```
Proto,Recv-Q,Send-Q,Local Address,Foreign Address,State,PID/Program name
tcp,0,0,123.345.789:1234,0.0.0.0:*,LISTEN,23044/test          
tcp,0,0,0.0.0.0:5915,0.0.0.0:*,LISTEN,99800/./serv    
tcp,0,0,0.0.0.0:1501,0.0.0.0:*,,-
```

```py
proto = data["Proto"]
for p in proto:
    print(p)
```

> Output: tcp tcp tcp

**What I've tried?:**

Where do I begin.. I've tried Splitting, Replacing and Translate. Also, I did try Regex but couldn't quite figure it out :/

```
Proto,Recv-Q,Send-Q,Local,Address,,,,,,,,,,,Foreign Address,,,,,,,,,State,,,,,, PID/Program,name    
tcp,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,0 123.345.789:1234,,,,,,,,0.0.0.0:*,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,LISTEN,,,,,,23021/java,,,,,,,,  
tcp,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,0 0.0.0.0:5915,,,,,,,,,,,,0.0.0.0:*,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,LISTEN,,,,,,99859/./statserv    
tcp,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,0 0.0.0.0:1501,,,,,,,,,,,,0.0.0.0:*,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,LISTEN,,,,,,-
```

Since some of the headers contain a space in between them it's sort of difficult to map the columns accordingly.

Looking for the best way to approach this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer updated to handle missing State value**

Skip the first row, indicate that there is no header, assign header names and then split on one or more spaces.

```
df = pd.read_csv(sim_txt, skiprows=1, header=None, sep='\s+', 
                 names=['Proto','cv-Q','Send-Q','Local Address','Foreign Address','State','PID/Program name']
                ).apply(row_fixer, axis=1) 
print(df)

  Proto  cv-Q  Send-Q     Local Address Foreign Address   State  PID/Program name
0   tcp     0       0  123.345.789:1234       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN        23044/test
1   tcp     0       0      0.0.0.0:5915       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      99800/./serv
2   tcp     0       0      0.0.0.0:5916       0.0.0.0:*     NaN      99801/./serv
3   tcp     0       0      0.0.0.0:1501       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN                 -

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=None)
```

The above depends on the following function.  It looks for a `NaN` the last column in the row which would indicate that the `State` value is missing. When that situation is found the last two values are swapped.  (Note: this function detects `NaN`s by leveraging the fact that `NaN != NaN`):

```
def row_fixer(x):
    if x.iat[-1] != x.iat[-1]:
        xc = x.copy()
        xc.iat[-1] = xc.iat[-2]
        xc.iat[-2] = np.NaN
        return xc    
    return x
```

The example above is based on the following example data:

```
Proto  cv-Q  Send-Q     Local Address Foreign Address   State  PID/Program name
  tcp     0       0  123.345.789:1234       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN        23044/test
  tcp     0       0      0.0.0.0:5915       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      99800/./serv
  tcp     0       0      0.0.0.0:5916       0.0.0.0:*              99801/./serv
  tcp     0       0      0.0.0.0:1501       0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN                 -
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works well however I forgot to add the fact that the column "State" sometimes has a missing value meaning, sometimes "LISTEN" is empty. This causes the neighbour columns data to be messed up.

Comment: @Jona Updated my answer to handle that situation

Answer (score 2):

You are post-processing the output of the `netstat` command.  `netstat` itself is just reformatting the information in `/proc/net/tcp`, which you can also read.  As with the `netstat` output, you may need to make your own header line, but the data lines are all space separated.  A simple `line.split()` should do it.

If you still want to use `netstat`, as I said, just throw away the header line and use `split`.  You know what the columns are.

```
for ln in output:
    fields = ln.split()
    print( ','.join(fields) )
```

Comment: Hey Tim, appreciate the reply.  Believe it or not, after trying to follow this I am still unable to pair or match-up the data based on the headers. Even after ignoring the headers, I am still left with countless amount of spaces in-between. Any other way of attempting this?

Comment: Remember that `ln.split(' ')` and `ln.split()` do two VERY different things.  My guess is you are doing the first, and that would produce the results you describe.  Passing no parameters to split treats a SERIES of whitespace as a single unit.

Answer (score 1):

Split based on a string with two or more spaces using a regex.

```
for ln in testset:
    splitted = re.split(r'\s{2,}', ln.replace("\n", ""))
    print(splitted)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and trying to help out! Appreciate it, Freeman.